# Central simple algebra of dimension 4

Tags: division-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $F$-central simple algebra with maximal subfield $E$ such that $[A:F] = 4$. if $N_{E/F}(E^*) \ne F^*$, then $A$ is a division algebra.

Is this even true? If it is true how i can prove it?
I know we have $A \simeq M_2(F)$ or $A$ is a division ring so we must show that $A$ isn't isomorphic with $M_2(F)$.

Comment: No, it's not true.  All quadratic extensions $E/F$ are contained in $M_2(F)$.

Comment: For example consider $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ and set: $$A = \left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y\\\overline{y} & \overline{x}
\end{pmatrix}
:x,y\in \mathbb{C}\right\rbrace \subseteq M_2(\mathbb{C})
$$. so A is a $\mathbb{R}$-central simple algebra and isn't division ring. is this counter-example correct?

Comment: Yes, your $A$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.